# Invertase calculation?

Tags: homework, enzymes

If I wanted to make $500\mathrm{\mu g}/\mathrm{ml}$ of invertase, from [Sigma's Invertase](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/i4504?lang=en&region=US) from Baker's yeast, which states is grade VII, and greater than or equal to $300 \mathrm{units}/\mathrm{ml}$, then **would these following calculations be right** if I wanted $10 \mathrm{ml}$ of $500 \mathrm{mg}/\mathrm{ml}$ concentration of enzyme solution?

\begin{align}
M_1\times V_1 & = M_2\times V_2 \\
(300 \mathrm{units} ??)\times V_1 & = 10 \mathrm{ml}\times(500 \mathrm{units} ??) \\
V_1 & = 16.6 \mathrm{ml}
\end{align}

Therefore I need $300 \mathrm{\mu g}$ of the powdered enzyme which is equal to $0.0003 \mathrm{g}$ and add up to $16.6 \mathrm{ml}$ of sodium acetate buffer, **to get my desired concentration of $500 \mathrm{\mu g}/\mathrm{ml}$?**

**Aside:** And also, would this solution be able to be made in a day in advance and stored cold or would the enzymes degrade too much?

EDIT:

After reading the comments, googling, and looking back at old protocols. Is the following calculation below right then?

I need $500\mathrm{\mu g}/\mathrm{ml}$ as my concentration, therefore if I want $10\mathrm{ml}$ of my solution:

$$
(500 \mathrm{\mu g}/1 \mathrm{ml})\times 10 \mathrm{ml} = 0.005 \mathrm{g}
$$

Therefore, $0.005 \mathrm{g}$ up to $10 \mathrm{ml}$ of buffer.

Comment: I cannot find on the website where Sigma states that the enzyme concentration is 300 mg/mL, which isn't surprising because it is sold as a dry powder. They do say that it is 300 units/mg. You could make a solution with specific mass concentration, though that wouldn't take into account impurities, such as salts remaining from lyophilization.

Comment: you have units all wrong. do you need grams/volume or units, or what?

Comment: ps. Units are usually defined by activity. Like, 1 unit of enzyme converts X moles of molecules in 1 hour. So, more pure, higher-quality stuff will have more units per gram or per mole

Comment: @canadianer     Yes. I misspoke it was 300units/mg. How from that can I get 500 ug/ml?

Comment: @aaaaaa        I need 500ug/ml as my concentration. So would 16.6ml of buffer with 300ug of powder get me that concentration? Or if not, how would  I do the calculations? Thanks.

Comment: If you want 10 mL of 500 ug/mL sample, you take 5 mg of powder and 10 mL of buffer

Comment: @canadianer      I just saw your comment as I was typing. thanks. I guess what I was confused about was the 300units/mg that they stated. I thought that had some bearing on my calculation.

Comment: ok, but are you sure you want ug/mL as final concentration, not units/mL? I would suggest double-checking

Comment: @aaaaaa.         Yes that is what I need, thanks.